# Use RSpec to test for DeserializationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a job that is enqueued. Sometimes, the record associated with that job is destroyed before the job is ran.

To resolve any `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` from being raised during the job's execution, I have added the following to the job:

```
rescue_from(ActiveJob::DeserializationError) do |exception|
  exception.original_exception == ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```

I would like to include tests for this so that I can verify that no `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` will be raised when a job runs with a record that has been destroyed.

To begin with testing, I removed the above function and decided to make sure I could test that the `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` is actually being thrown. The spec for this is:

```
it "raises DeserializationError when a record is destroyed before perform" do
  record = create(:record)

  record.destroy

  expect{ RecordDeletionJob.perform_later(record) }.to raise_error(ActiveJob::DeserializationError)
end
```

To my surprise, the spec fails because nothing was raised. This is incorrect. Without the `rescue_from` method, it should be raising a `ActiveJob::DeserializationError`.

I assumed the problem was that the record was not being reloaded but I do not know how to reload the record after its destruction and how to test for the `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` after that.

How can I test that `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` is not thrown in the case that the record does not exist when the job runs?

Comment: Does this work if you replace `perform_later` with `perform_now`?

Comment: It does not. That may have been an error in my original question because I actually began testing with perform_now

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to test this:

```rails
it "retries 5 times" do
  serialized_args = [
        {
          "_aj_ruby2_keywords" => [
            "entity",
          ],
          "entity" => {
            "_aj_globalid"=> "gid://app/Entity/6ec11df7-ccf3-45ee-bc1c-f61821ef0aa2"
          }
        }
      ]
  subject.serialized_arguments = serialized_args
  4.times { subject.perform_now }
  expect { subject.perform_now }.to raise_exception(ActiveJob::DeserializationError)
end
```